# How to make Imagemagick show the colorspace as Uncalibrated/Unknown/Undeclared when it is undeclared?

Tags: imagemagick, color-space, imagemagick-identify

I use the `identify` command of ImageMagick to retrieve exif of a photo. ImageMagick, unlike exiftool, returns `sRGB` when the colorspace has been undeclared. How can I make ImageMagick return either `Uncalibrated` or `Unknown` or `Undeclared` when it is the case?

Comment: I do not think that is possible when using identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred's right. You'll need to use some additional utilities (like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk))  in addition to some `-format [EXIF:*]` magick.

```
identify -format '%[EXIF:Col*ce]\n' input_file.tif | \
   awk '{ if (length($0)) { print $0; exit } else { print "Uncalibrated" }}'
```

This works by invoking a query (`*`) character which will attempt to return a list of key-matches. If the key `EXIF:Colorspace` is set, awk will print it, else `"Uncalibrated"` would be returned.

Another option is `identify -debug Coder input_file.tif` which will dump *all* the data-points ImageMagick extracts from the image format. But that may be overkill.